# Parsing of a XML response

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am completely new to XML.

I have a URL which gives me a XML response. I am facing problems in parsing the response and showing only the details that I want. Currently the url is "https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55504&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=%3CHotelListRequest%3E%3Ccity%3ESeattle%3C%2Fcity%3E%3CstateProvinceCode%3EWA%3C%2FstateProvinceCode%3E%3CcountryCode%3EUS%3C%2FcountryCode%3E%3CarrivalDate%3E%3C%2FarrivalDate%3E%3CdepartureDate%3E9%2F1%2F2014%3C%2FdepartureDate%3E%3CRoomGroup%3E%3CRoom%3E%3CnumberOfAdults%3E2%3C%2FnumberOfAdults%3E%3C%2FRoom%3E%3C%2FRoomGroup%3E%3CnumberOfResults%3E25%3C%2FnumberOfResults%3E%3C%2FHotelListRequest%3E"

and I am using the following code:

```
$feed = file_get_contents($url);
$items = simplexml_load_string($feed);
print_r($items);
```

and this was the error
 file_get_contents( https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55504&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=%3CHotelListRequest%3E%3Ccity%3EAmsterdam%3C%2Fcity%3E%3CarrivalDate%3E08/30/2014%3C%2FarrivalDate%3E%3CdepartureDate%3E08/31/2014%3C%2FdepartureDate%3E%3CRoomGroup%3E%3CRoom%3E%3CnumberOfAdults%3E1%3C%2FnumberOfAdults%3E%3C%2FRoom%3E%3C%2FRoomGroup%3E%3CnumberOfResults%3E25%3C%2FnumberOfResults%3E%3C%2FHotelListRequest%3E): failed to open stream: Invalid argument

I have also tried using `simplexml_load_file()` and it's showing the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_get_contents` on the URL is returning content of type json, that's why `simple_xml_load_file` cannot parse it. Use this

```
$feed =  file_get_contents("https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55504&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=%3CHotelListRequest%3E%3Ccity%3ESeattle%3C%2Fcity%3E%3CstateProvinceCode%3EWA%3C%2FstateProvinceCode%3E%3CcountryCode%3EUS%3C%2FcountryCode%3E%3CarrivalDate%3E%3C%2FarrivalDate%3E%3CdepartureDate%3E9%2F1%2F2014%3C%2FdepartureDate%3E%3CRoomGroup%3E%3CRoom%3E%3CnumberOfAdults%3E2%3C%2FnumberOfAdults%3E%3C%2FRoom%3E%3C%2FRoomGroup%3E%3CnumberOfResults%3E25%3C%2FnumberOfResults%3E%3C%2FHotelListRequest%3E");
//echo $feed;

$json = json_decode($feed);

print_r($json);
```

Comment: any idea on how do i print the results i desire and not everything, as in the results are getting printed as an array of object. I want it to print only names of the hotel and nothing else

Comment: $json = json_decode($feed,true);
$arr = $json['HotelListResponse']['HotelList']['HotelSummary'];
 foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
 {
   print_r($value["name"]." ");
 }

Answer (score 1):

Currently when viewed on the browser its an xml but in the script is responds a json.

```
$url = 'https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55504&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=%3CHotelListRequest%3E%3Ccity%3ESeattle%3C%2Fcity%3E%3CstateProvinceCode%3EWA%3C%2FstateProvinceCode%3E%3CcountryCode%3EUS%3C%2FcountryCode%3E%3CarrivalDate%3E%3C%2FarrivalDate%3E%3CdepartureDate%3E9%2F1%2F2014%3C%2FdepartureDate%3E%3CRoomGroup%3E%3CRoom%3E%3CnumberOfAdults%3E2%3C%2FnumberOfAdults%3E%3C%2FRoom%3E%3C%2FRoomGroup%3E%3CnumberOfResults%3E25%3C%2FnumberOfResults%3E%3C%2FHotelListRequest%3E';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($contents, true);
// becomes an array
```